# Warning: 'news' is an entry point defined in pyproject.toml, but it's not installed as a script. You may get improper `sys.argv[0]`

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

- I am trying to run my poetry based python project inside docker using docker compose
- When I run the application, it works but it gives me this warning

```
ch_news_dev_python          | Warning: 'news' is an entry point defined in pyproject.toml, but it's not installed as a script. You may get improper `sys.argv[0]`.
ch_news_dev_python          | 
ch_news_dev_python          | The support to run uninstalled scripts will be removed in a future release.
ch_news_dev_python          | 
ch_news_dev_python          | Run `poetry install` to resolve and get rid of this message.
```

**My project structure**

```
news
├── docker
│   ├── development
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── python_server
│   │   │   └── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── .env
│   │   └── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── production
│   │   └── ...
│   └── test
│       └── ...
├── src
│   └── news
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       ├── app.py
│       └── ...
├── tests
├── .gitignore
├── pyproject.toml
├── poetry.lock
└── ...
```

**My python_server/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10.11-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y gcc libffi-dev g++\
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.5.0

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

RUN groupadd --gid 10000 ch_news \
    && useradd --uid 10000 --gid ch_news --shell /bin/bash --create-home ch_news

WORKDIR /home/ch_news

COPY --chown=10000:10000 pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

USER ch_news

RUN poetry install --no-root --no-ansi --without dev

COPY --chown=10000:10000 ./src ./

CMD ["poetry", "run", "news"]
```

**My docker-compose file**

```
version: '3.9' # optional since v1.27.0
name: ch_news_dev
services:
  ...

  ch_news_dev_python:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/python_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_news_dev_python
    depends_on:
      ch_news_dev_postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_news_dev_python_image
    networks:
      - network
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - postgres_certs:/home/ch_news/certs

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_certs:
    driver: local
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

**My pyproject.toml file**

```
[tool.poetry]
authors = ["..."]
description = "..."
name = "news"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
feedparser = "^6.0.10"
python = "^3.10"
aiohttp = "^3.8.4"
python-dateutil = "^2.8.2"
asyncpg = "^0.27.0"
loguru = "^0.7.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
commitizen = "^3.2.2"
pre-commit = "^3.3.2"
pytest = "^7.3.1"
pytest-cov = "^4.0.0"
tox = "^4.5.1"

bandit = "^1.7.5"
black = "^23.3.0"
darglint = "^1.8.1"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
flake8-bugbear = "^23.5.9"
flake8-docstrings = "^1.7.0"
isort = "^5.12.0"
mypy = "^1.3.0"
pytest-clarity = "^1.0.1"
pytest-sugar = "^0.9.7"
typeguard = "^4.0.0"
xdoctest = "^1.1.0"
aioresponses = "^0.7.4"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.21.0"
types-python-dateutil = "^2.8.19"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
isort = "^5.12.0"
types-python-dateutil = "^2.8.19.7"
flake8-docstrings = "^1.7.0"
xdoctest = "^1.1.1"
pre-commit = "^3.3.2"
commitizen = "^3.2.2"
tox = "^4.5.1"
mypy = "^1.3.0"
pytest = "^7.3.1"
flake8-bugbear = "^23.5.9"
black = "^23.3.0"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.21.0"
bandit = "^1.7.5"
typeguard = "^4.0.0"
pytest-sugar = "^0.9.7"

[tool.coverage.run]
branch = true
omit = ["src/news/__main__.py", "src/news/app.py"]
source = ["news"]

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "src"
addopts = [
    "--import-mode=importlib",
]

[tool.coverage.report]
fail_under = 95

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
src_paths = ["src", "tests"]
skip_gitignore = true
force_single_line = true
atomic = true
color_output = true

[tool.mypy]
pretty = true
show_column_numbers = true
show_error_codes = true
show_error_context = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
strict = true
warn_unreachable = true

[tool.poetry.scripts]
news = "news.__main__:app"

[tool.commitizen]
name = "cz_conventional_commits"
tag_format = "v$major.$minor.$patch$prerelease"
version = "0.0.1"
[build-system]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
```

Can someone kindly tell me how to get rid of this warning?

**UPDATE 1**

Getting the warning even after removing --no-root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is related to the fact that the entry point is declared in poetry
in your file pyproject.toml :

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
news = "news.__main__:app"
```

after declaring the entry point, you must execute the command

```
poetry install
```

in your terminal

Comment: `poetry install` does nothing. I still get the error.

Comment: @CalebFenton Same for me, it does nothing !

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too when building without virtualenv. Fallbacked to run scripts with `python path/to/script.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Name of src directory in project should be the same as name in toml (4th line of `pyproject.toml`)

So you should rename your src directory to `"news"`. Or (as an option) you can change `name = "news"` to `'name = "src"'` in 4th line of your toml.

Answer (score -2):

You docker file shows, that you are running `poetry install` with the `--no-root` flag. Entrypoints are part of your package, so they get only installed when the package is installed as well. You have to run `poetry install` without the `--no-root` flag.

I don't see any reason, why you are using `--no-root`. Without installing the project itself, it's just luck that your `import` statements are working.

Comment: Removed no-root inside docker, still getting that warning